# How to run a process in the Background with C without exec

Tags: c, shell, background, fork

Hello everyone I am currenlty working on creating a shell in c that can execute commands in the background, while allowing the user to contuine executing commands in the forground. Like how you can in Lniux. However, I don't want to the background process to run on the host shell, I want it to run my shell that I have made. So I know I can't use the execl function to do this. Would anyone know what kind of function I would need to do this? I know I need to create a fork to make a child and parent process. Once that is done I would execute the background command in the child and not call wait in the parent. But I don't know if there is a function I need for executing in the background or not.

Thank you for anyhelp!

Answer (score 1):

The function you need is called `exec`... pretty much all other functions that execute other are wrappers for `execve` system call, possibly coupled with a `fork` before. But there is no other function in Linux to `exec`ute another program but the `exec` family.